# converting a string to json format in scala

Tags: json, string, scala

I have to convert a string to json format in `scala`. The string is like this:

```
"classification" : "Map(Metals -> List(Cu, Co, Ni), Nonmetals -> List(N,O,C), Noblegases -> List(Ar, Kr))"
```

The desired json format is like this:

```
"classification" : {"Metals": [Cu, Co, Ni],
                    "Nonmetals":[N,O,C],
                    "Noblegases":[Ar, Kr]
                    }
```

Any quick suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you need to write some code to do this. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? And do you really have a String holding the representation of a Scala Map? If so you should go back and ask for something more useful (for instance, you're going run into difficulties if any of your keys or values contain quotes or parens)

Comment: Is `Map(Metals -> List(Cu, Co, Ni), Nonmetals -> List(N,O,C), Noblegases -> List(Ar, Kr))` a String or do you get an actual Map?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok that's a string.

Comment: Shouldn't the metals be in quotes, too? E.g. `["N", "O", "C"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific so my answer is a bit vague as well.

First you will have to parse the input string and extract the values. I would use a combination of regular expressions and simple String operations like searching for the first occurrence of a certain character (e.g. colon) and splitting the string there.

In the next step you create the JSON object. There are several libraries out there that you can use. I suggest [JSON-Java/org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) or if you like to use a scala library you can use [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson).